# Adding menu to SWT tables

Tags: java, menu, swt, menuitem

I want to add same menu on multiple tables(SWT table). When user clicks on menu items, I want to detect the table associated with that menu. Here is the code below.

```
 private void setMenu(Table table) {
        Listener popUpListener = new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                MenuItem item = (MenuItem)event.widget;
                Menu pare = item.getParent();
                Decorations fdf = pare.getParent();
                                    //Code to get table name or instance of table.

            }
        };
        Menu menu = new Menu(table); // where table1 is your table
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item1.setText("Copy cell");
        item1.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item2.setText("Copy row");
        item2.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item3.setText("Copy column");
        item3.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
        MenuItem item4 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
        item4.setText("Copy all");
        item4.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
        table.setMenu(menu);
    }
```

setMenu method is called multiple times sending the instances of table.
How I can detect the table associated with the currently popped up menu in pop-up listener.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `Table` you send to the method `final`:

```
private void setMenu(final Table table) {
    Listener popUpListener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            MenuItem item = (MenuItem)event.widget;
            Menu pare = item.getParent();
            Decorations fdf = pare.getParent();

            // Now you can access the table from within the Listener
            System.out.println(table);
        }
    };
    Menu menu = new Menu(table); // where table1 is your table
    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item1.setText("Copy cell");
    item1.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
    MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item2.setText("Copy row");
    item2.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
    MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item3.setText("Copy column");
    item3.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
    MenuItem item4 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item4.setText("Copy all");
    item4.addListener(SWT.Selection, popUpListener);
    table.setMenu(menu);
}
```